# What is wrong with the way I am using SOAP in this specic MATLAB example?

Tags: web-services, debugging, matlab, dom, soap

I am trying to connect to an example soap server at http://www.webservicex.net/ using the following MATLAB code:

```
% createSoapMessage(NAMESPACE,METHOD,VALUES,NAMES,TYPES,STYLE) creates a SOAP message.
% VALUES, NAMES, and TYPES are cell arrays.  
m = createSoapMessage('http://www.webserviceX.NET', 'GetCitiesByCountry', ...
  {'Australia'}, {'CountryName'}, { '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string' }, 'rpc')

%    callSoapService(ENDPOINT,SOAPACTION,MESSAGE) sends the MESSAGE,
%    a Java DOM, to the SOAPACTION service at the ENDPOINT.
response = callSoapService('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL', ...
  'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry', m);
```

I get the following response (with line endings inserted for viewing):

```
val =
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
          Server was unable to process request. 
          ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
          Procedure or function 'getWCity' expects parameter '@CountryName',
          which was not supplied.
          at WebServicex.GlobalWeather.GetCitiesByCountry(String CountryName)
          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        </faultstring><detail />
      </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I know that the server is responding. I can interrogate it with Python and suds like this:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.GetCitiesByCountry('Australia')
```

My simple question is what am I doing wrong?

I would also like to know how to view the DOM object that createSoapMessage creates and how to view the xml that MATLAB sends and receives.

Comment: I have partly answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220900/sending-soap-request-with-matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code looks like this:

```
% createSoapMessage(NAMESPACE,METHOD,VALUES,NAMES,TYPES,STYLE) creates a SOAP message.
message = createSoapMessage( ...
  'http://www.webserviceX.NET', ...
  'GetCitiesByCountry', ...
  {'Australia'}, ...
  {'CountryName'}, ...
  {'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string' }, ...
  'document')

% callSoapService(ENDPOINT,SOAPACTION,MESSAGE) sends the MESSAGE,
response = callSoapService( ...
  'http://www.webservicex.net/GlobalWeather.asmx', ...
  'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry', ...
  message);

% parseSoapResponse Convert the response from a SOAP server into MATLAB types.
cities = parseSoapResponse(response)
```

The particular differences are:

- The STYLE parameter is 'document', not 'rpc'
- www.webservicex.net is very inconsistent in how they capitalize, and it matters!
- The endpoint parameter ends .asmx and does not inclcude ?WDSL.

I have added an example of the `parseSoapResponse` call too. This also caused me trouble. For this web service, this call returns just the structure containing the requested data. When working with a different service on the same host, `parseSoapResponse` returned two outputs, a good/bad result and the data. See [sending SOAP request with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220900/sending-soap-request-with-matlab).

Finally, in answer to my supplementary question about viewing the intermediate XML such as `message`, the soap message, in MATLAB, use the following:

```
 javaString = message.saveXML(message.getFirstChild())
```

to get the XML in a java string and then:

```
 matlabString = char(javaString)
```

to get the XML in a matlab string.

The following code adds newlines and spaces to display the XML over several lines to help debugging.

```
ms2 = regexprep(matlabString ,'>','>\n')
ms3 = regexprep(ms2,' x','\n  x')
```

I still do not know how to view the outgoing and incoming HTTP traffic in MATLAB like you can in a browser.